# How should I include hyperparameters in my saved TensorFlow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently saving hyperparameters as `tf.constant`:s in a collection, but to read them I then have to evaluate them (e.g. `sess.run`). Is there a better way of including fixed hyperparameters with a TensorFlow model, that will be compatible with TensorFlow Serving, Google Cloud, etc.?

This is how I save hyperparameters with my graph as of now:

```
hyperparameters = {'foo': foo,
                   'bar': bar}
for k, v in hyperparameters.items():
    tf.add_to_collection('CONSTANTS', tf.constant(value=v, name=k))
```

And later when I want to read the hyperparameters from a saved graph:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

hyperparameters = {}
for c in tf.get_collection('CONSTANTS'):
    hyperparameters[c.op.name] = c.eval()
```

Comment: I see FLAGS used a lot, but personally I do it similarly to you. This related question might be interesting to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38510339/the-usage-or-api-of-tf-app-flags